# Postman - Transfer Get Response to Post Body

Tags: postman

I'm working on validating a large amount of data. My Get request returns a JSON file with all of the information I need. My Put request needs to have all of that information, but also modify a few fields. Right now, I save all of the fields as separate environment variables, which are then pumped into the Put body.

Is there a quicker way of doing this, since I'm working with around ~100 different fields? Can I save the entire Get request in a single variable, which I then place in the Put? It hasn't worked so far, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the answer here https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1825

Comment: Do you want to close out the question, if you have found a solution that works for you?